# GEE Export.image.toCloudStorage option 'skipEmptyTiles' in Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am attempting to save an image from GEE to Google Cloud Storage within the Python API using [ee.batch.Export.image.toCloudStorage](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/export-image-tocloudstorage). The documentation suggests that `skipEmptyTiles` can be set to true to skip writing fully-masked image tiles. However, when I use this option, it returns the error:

```
ee.ee_exception.EEException: Unknown configuration options: {'skipEmptyTiles': True}
```

Here is example code:

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()
bucket_name = 'trial-bucket'

# Region and time of interest
aoi = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017").filter("country_na == 'Rwanda'").first().geometry()
yoi = '2022'

# Sentinel-2 & NDVI data
s2 = (ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
      .filterBounds(aoi)
      .filter(ee.Filter.date(yoi))
      .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 60)))

def compute_ndvi(img):
    ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('ndvi')
    return img.addBands([ndvi])
ndvi = s2.map(compute_ndvi).select('ndvi').max()

# Cropland
dw = (ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1')
        .filterBounds(aoi)
        .filter(ee.Filter.date(yoi)))
dw_crop = dw.select('label').mode().eq(4).rename('cropland')  # Equal to 1 if LULC = crop (value of 4); Otherwise equal to 0

# Mask NDVI data to cropland
ndvi_masked = ndvi.updateMask(dw_crop)

# Export to Cloud Storage
image_task = ee.batch.Export.image.toCloudStorage(
    image=ndvi_masked,
    description=f"{yoi}_Peak_NDVI",
    bucket=bucket_name,
    scale=10,
    crs='EPSG:4326',
    maxPixels=2e8,
    fileFormat='TFRecord',
    region=aoi,
    skipEmptyTiles=True
)
```

Comment: That's a bug (confirmed).  Bug report filed.